# how to get pixel coordinates of an element on computer screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know the left and top position of an html element on the screen.
I tried with this code that gives me the position of an element inside a document:

```
var position = $('#elem').position();
```

but what I want is to know if there is a function that finds the position on the screen, or if there is a way to know the coordinates of this point on the screen: [image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect).

> The returned value is a TextRectangle object, which contains read-only
>   left, top, right and bottom properties describing the border-box in
>   pixels. top and left are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

For example, this is the result for question element on not scrolled page:

```
document.querySelector("#question").getBoundingClientRect()
```

```
{
    "height": 633,
    "width": 728,
    "left": 431.5,
    "bottom": 844,
    "right": 1159.5,
    "top": 211
}
```

And a bit scrolled:

```
{
    "height": 633,
    "width": 728,
    "left": 431.5,
    "bottom": 10,
    "right": 1159.5,
    "top": -623
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [offset api](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

instead [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) the coordinates are relative to the parent element

Answer (score 0):

you need to define what positon you want to find `top` `left`

check documentation [Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
var position = $('#elem').position();
alert(position.left + ' ' + position.top)
```